# Should a fallback SMTP server filter/screen incoming email the same way as the primary server?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Let's suppose we have an SMTP server called `alpha.example.com`, which is the only MX server listed for `example.com`.

Like most modern email SMTP servers, rejects emails not bound for its group of virtual users, rejects incoming email from spamhaus listed domains, runs mail through SpamAssassin, checks SPF records, all of that good stuff.

However, being the only MX record listed for `example.com`, there's a concern that if the machine is taken down for maintenance, email may be delayed. Well behaved other SMTP servers will obviously queue, and retry later, but that could introduce some tens of minutes or hours of delay, even if the primary is brought down for a small amount of time if it coincides with an attempted delivery.

We want to start a secondary SMTP server, which let's call `beta.example.com`, which will be listed as the lower priority MX record. But `alpha.example.com` is still where all the mail is stored, it's still where all the users connect their MUAs to. So `beta.example.com` will just store-and-forward email to `alpha.example.com`, since it's not the "endpoint".

**My question is: Does `beta` need to also run its email through the same checks as `alpha`? ie. checking for virtual users, spamhaus, SPF lookups, DKIM checks, or is the fact that those things are checked on `alpha` when the email is delivered is sufficient**

Also, will `beta` relaying the emails to `alpha` fall afoul of those emails SPF lookups, given that `beta.example.com` is unlikely to be listed as a valid sender of `arbitary.org`'s emails.

Technically I'm using Postfix for SMTP (and Dovecot for the authentication/IMAP side), in case that informs the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the secondary server run the same type of checks doesn't cost anything, so why not just do it?

Some other reasons:

- You would have to adapt your primary server to correctly handle mails from the secondary server like they come from one hop before. Your SPF concern is valid and by default would be a problem. Assuming filtering has already happened is much simpler.
- Most antispam solutions will reject some mails before they are completely transmitted (e.g. right after the EHLO message or after the TO header). Without these filters, you now first have to accept those and fully deal with them on the primary server. In some jurisdictions, this can even become a legal problem (e.g. in certain constellations, it is acceptable to outright reject a mail, with the sender knowing this, but it's not OK to first accept the mail and then delete it anyway in further filtering steps, without the sender knowing this).

Answer (score 1):

Parsing `Authentication-Results` of your backup MX is not the real problem here. [RFC 7601](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7601) describes solid mechanisms for dealing with potential abuse - you remove obviously spoofed headers during header cleanup and tell your validation software to trust the results determined by your backup mx (`TrustedAuthServIDs beta.example.com` in `opendmarc.conf`).

Yet **No**, running a secondary MX with the same configuration as the primary MX defeats much of the original purpose for deploying it:

1. There is a non-zero probability that your primary mail server outage is caused by one of your mail filtering programs - if you just duplicate the setup, one bad *spamassassin* update breaks both, one bad SPF validator update breaks both, .. A backup MX that likely fails from a shared root cause is not worth much.
2. You primary mail server probably already filters mail based on statistical data (e.g. *Bayesian Filtering*) which is hard to keep in sync between primary and backup mx. If you really setup mail screening on backup mx the way it is on primary mx - and that data is different, you will either degrade your spam filtering quality - or send more bounces (eww).
3. If your task is to ensure some service level like "98% of yearly non-spam mail must show up in IMAP within 60 seconds" you have already got tons of room for unscheduled maintenance. It is entirely possible that potential service level improvement versus the recurring administrative cost for running the backup MX end up making any remotely complex backup MX setup "not worth it".

Comment: What if the outage is just caused by routine system reboots, restarting, that sort of thing?

Comment: @coiax Sure that is downtime.. but these days, it is going to be about 23 seconds at 3:10 in the morning, about once a month. You can probably find another single point of failure with worse service quality properties than that.

Comment: So, following this logic, when would you ever actually want a secondary MX server?

Comment: @coiax when the primary is no longer *"where all the mail is stored"*